# A science fiction series with a pilot merged with the ship

Tags: story-identification

I have a vague memory of a science fiction television series I saw when I was a child (probably late 90's). The main thing that I remember about it is a space-ship which was partly organic and the pilot was in some way grafted to the ship, essentially becoming one organism.

I also have a vague memory of blankets made from litmus, which was a convenient way of discovering imposters by the acidity of their blood.

Has anyone got a clue what this was?

Comment: Homeworld (video game) also has a similar concept, as a FYI. Of course, that's relevant really only within the story line of the game and not in actual game play. There's no blankets, though  :p

Comment: Is this a book series or a television series?  When did you first see or read this?  In what language?  Can you guess when it could have been created or published?  Eg. does it have computerized special effects, is it black and white?

Comment: FYI, if you like the concept, you may like Evangelion

Comment: Try finding links to "Lexx". I was recently looking for the same series and am pretty sure this is the one you want.

Comment: @numbat The answer was definitely Farscape. The answer even identified the litmus blankets.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The first part sounds like Farscape (1999~2003), a race called Leviathans are used as ships, being bonded with a race simply known as 'Pilot'.

Thanks to @JC2K8 we also know that the litmus blankets were in episode 1x18, A Bug's Life.

Comment: The title made me think of Anne McCaffery's The Ship Who Sang and sequels. Reading the question I realised they were too early, and not on TV.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang#Brain_&_Brawn_Ship_series